# jQuery Delay Queue not working

Tags: jquery, image, delay

I've been trying to get the .delay() method to work on this one line but it immediatly empties out the content even when I set the delay method prior to the .empty() method.

Here is my code:

```
$('.work_thumbs').fadeTo(200, 0).delay(200).empty();
```

'.work_thumbs' is a set of images that I want to vanish and then once they've finished dissapearing I want the elements with that class to be emptied out so that the images effectively dissapear.

But they just dissapear completely because the .empty() method run's and complete ignores the .delay() method, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout function to delay your script, like this,

```
$('.work_thumbs').fadeTo(200, 0);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.work_thumbs').empty();
}, 2000);
```